# Load testing of server application in unit tests and in while box testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, load, webserver, load-testing

How to do load testing of server applications in junit tests and in white box testing.

Load testing here I meant, how to find out how many client connections (from same or different IP) can be connected to server without affecting the performance of the server machine and the application. The performance here includes, RAM (Memory usage), Load on the cores, Speed of the processing etc.

How to find this without using any external third party library or application? How to write such unit tests in Junit?

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend you use third part application to perform load testing of your application - LoadRunner, LoadUI or JMeter. If you'll decide to use JMeter, you have ability to use JMEter plugin - [Performance Monitor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)  to know the health of the servers loaded. You can start working with JMeter with [this](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/197560-jmeter-video-tutorial-writing-your-first-jmeter-s) video tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You really have about a dozen questions embedded in your one.   The question on Unit testing is a whole category unto itself, as is performance testing (which is more than just "connections...").

It is time to either attend training or hire someone who has done this work before where you can attach yourself to them for a period of time to watch, learn, take notes and ask lots of questions!

While JMETER has been mentioned, any tool is only somewhere between 5-15% of the total skills and working knowledge that you need to be successful with performance testing.